# ApplicationSignInManager could not be found?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I having this issue, 'ApplicationSignInManager could not be found' on my StartUp.cs file. This file access the members and class definition to IdentityConfig.cs What could be an issue, i have correct dll under bin and using version Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Ownin version 2.2.0. See my logic below and provide necessary help.

```
    // IdentityConfig.cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using eNtsaTrainingRegistration.Models;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Net;
using System.Web.Configuration;

namespace eNtsaTrainingRegistration
{
    public class EmailService : IIdentityMessageService
    {
        public Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
        {
            var mailMessage = new MailMessage();
            mailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(message.Destination));
            mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("Gcobani Mkontwana <ggcobani@gmail.com>");
            mailMessage.Subject = message.Subject;
            mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
            mailMessage.Body = message.Body;

            using(var smtp = new SmtpClient())
            {
                var credential = new NetworkCredential
                {
                    UserName = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserName"],
                    Password = Helper_b.Decrypt(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserPassword"])
                };
                smtp.Credentials = credential;
                smtp.Host = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SMTPName"];
                smtp.Port = int.Parse(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SMTPPort"]);
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                smtp.Send(mailMessage);
            }
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }

        public class SmsService : IIdentityMessageService
        {
            public Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
            {
                return Task.FromResult(0);
            }
        }

        // add another method here.
        public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
        {
            public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser> store)
                : base(store)
            {
            }

            public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options, IOwinContext context)
            {
                var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
                // Configure validation logic for usernames
                manager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(manager)
                {
                    AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
                    RequireUniqueEmail = true
                };

                // Configure validation logic for passwords
                manager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
                {
                    RequiredLength = 6,
                    RequireNonLetterOrDigit = true,
                    RequireDigit = true,
                    RequireLowercase = true,
                    RequireUppercase = true,
                };

                // Configure user lockout defaults
                manager.UserLockoutEnabledByDefault = true;
                manager.DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
                manager.MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout = 5;

                // Register two factor authentication providers. This application uses Phone and Emails as a step of receiving a code for verifying the user
                // You can write your own provider and plug it in here.
                manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("Phone Code", new PhoneNumberTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>
                {
                    MessageFormat = "Your security code is {0}"
                });
                manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("Email Code", new EmailTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>
                {
                    Subject = "Security Code",
                    BodyFormat = "Your security code is {0}"
                });
                manager.EmailService = new EmailService();
                manager.SmsService = new SmsService();
                var dataProtectionProvider = options.DataProtectionProvider;
                if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
                {
                    manager.UserTokenProvider =
                        new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"));
                }
                return manager;
            }
        }

    // SignInManager class.
    public class ApplicationSignInManager:SignInManager<ApplicationUser, string>
    {
        public ApplicationSignInManager(ApplicationUserManager userManager, IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager)
        : base(userManager, authenticationManager)
        {
        }

        public override Task<ClaimsIdentity> CreateUserIdentityAsync(ApplicationUser user)
        {
            return user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync((ApplicationUserManager)UserManager);
        }

        public static ApplicationSignInManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationSignInManager> options, IOwinContext context)
        {
            return new ApplicationSignInManager(context.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>(), context.Authentication);
        }
    }

}
```

}

```
// Startup.cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies;
using Owin;
using eNtsaTrainingRegistration.Models;

namespace eNtsaTrainingRegistration
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create); // Error is here 'ApplicationSignInManager could be found'.
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: can you include the namespace of your IdentityConfig.cs?

Comment: javachipper i just included, please check

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here, copy and paste this one:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Net;
using System.Web.Configuration;

namespace eNtsaTrainingRegistration
{
    public class EmailService : IIdentityMessageService
    {
        public Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
        {
            var mailMessage = new MailMessage();
            mailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(message.Destination));
            mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("Gcobani Mkontwana <ggcobani@gmail.com>");
            mailMessage.Subject = message.Subject;
            mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
            mailMessage.Body = message.Body;

            using (var smtp = new SmtpClient())
            {
                var credential = new NetworkCredential
                {
                    UserName = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserName"],
                    Password = Helper_b.Decrypt(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserPassword"])
                };
                smtp.Credentials = credential;
                smtp.Host = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SMTPName"];
                smtp.Port = int.Parse(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SMTPPort"]);
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                smtp.Send(mailMessage);
            }
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
    }

    public class SmsService : IIdentityMessageService
    {
        public Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
    }
    // add another method here.
    public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser> store)
            : base(store)
        {
        }

        public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options, IOwinContext context)
        {
            var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
            // Configure validation logic for usernames
            manager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(manager)
            {
                AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
                RequireUniqueEmail = true
            };

            // Configure validation logic for passwords
            manager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
            {
                RequiredLength = 6,
                RequireNonLetterOrDigit = true,
                RequireDigit = true,
                RequireLowercase = true,
                RequireUppercase = true,
            };

            // Configure user lockout defaults
            manager.UserLockoutEnabledByDefault = true;
            manager.DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
            manager.MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout = 5;

            // Register two factor authentication providers. This application uses Phone and Emails as a step of receiving a code for verifying the user
            // You can write your own provider and plug it in here.
            manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("Phone Code", new PhoneNumberTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>
            {
                MessageFormat = "Your security code is {0}"
            });
            manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("Email Code", new EmailTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>
            {
                Subject = "Security Code",
                BodyFormat = "Your security code is {0}"
            });
            manager.EmailService = new EmailService();
            manager.SmsService = new SmsService();
            var dataProtectionProvider = options.DataProtectionProvider;
            if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
            {
                manager.UserTokenProvider =
                    new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"));
            }
            return manager;
        }
    }
    // SignInManager class.
    public class ApplicationSignInManager : SignInManager<ApplicationUser, string>
    {
        public ApplicationSignInManager(ApplicationUserManager userManager, IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager)
        : base(userManager, authenticationManager)
        {
        }

        public override Task<ClaimsIdentity> CreateUserIdentityAsync(ApplicationUser user)
        {
            return user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync((ApplicationUserManager)UserManager);
        }

        public static ApplicationSignInManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationSignInManager> options, IOwinContext context)
        {
            return new ApplicationSignInManager(context.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>(), context.Authentication);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem was in your IdentityConfig.cs file. The ApplicationSignInManager became an inner class of EmailService. Might be the reason why it can't find it.

Comment: Javachipper please tell me the work around there? I seem dont comprehend well as to what happened exactly? Was the issue not on the newest package Microsoft.AspNet.Identity?

Comment: You told me you had all the references needed for it to work, I trusted you. So the only thing that It couldn't find it would be the namespace. As it turned out it was because of your curly braces.

Comment: Glad I could help mate